# WYSIWYG editor's button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm up to upgrade my "wysiwyg" editor by adding new buttons to the toolbar. One of these buttons is called "add a slideshow" which works this way :

- when I click the button, it shows up a popup window which tells me to add pictures that are gonna be in the slideshow.
- then when I choose the pictures, a simple slideshow will be created and shown in the editor.

I made some research in the net and I found an enormous number of slideshow codes that each time when you wanna change the slide, you have to go to html code and change the attribute's value ... So instead of that, I just wanna make it easier to the user by doing this "popup window + automatic add of the pic to the slideshow"

If anyone of you guys have an idea about this, please help me to achieve this work.

PS: Sorry for my poor English :p

Answer (score 0):

The unfortunate thing about wysiwyg text editors is, while some have options, usually what you see is what you get.